# Internet explorer and floats: please explain

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

Yesterday someone asked [Width absorbing HTML elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820473/width-absorbing-html-elements). I presented [two solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820473/width-absorbing-html-elements/820580#820580): one table-based and one pure CSS. Now the pure CSS one works well in Firefox and Chrome but not in IE.

Basically the floats are being bumped down to the next line. It is my understanding (and the behaviour of FF and Chrome) that this should not be the case because the left divs are block level elements that floats should basically ignore.

Complete code example is below. Adding a DOCTYPE to force IE into standards compliant mode helps slightly but the problem remains.

So my question is: am I mistaken about my understanding of floats or is this IE's problem?

More importantly, how do I get this to work in IE? It's been bugging the hell out of me.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
div div { height: 1.3em; }
#wrapper { width: 300px; overflow: hidden; }
div.text { float: right; white-space: nowrap; clear: both; background: white; padding-left: 12px; text-align: left; }
#row1, #row2, #row3, #row4, #row5, #row6 { width: 270px; margin-bottom: 4px; }
#row1 { background: red; }
#row2 { background: blue; }
#row3 { background: green; }
#row4 { background: yellow; }
#row5 { background: pink; }
#row6 { background: gray; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("jquery", "1.3.2");
google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
  $(function() {
    $("div.text").animate({ width: "90%" }, 2000);
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div class="text">FOO</div><div id="row1"></div>
<div class="text">BAR</div><div id="row2"></div>
<div class="text">THESE PRETZELS ARE</div><div id="row3"></div>
<div class="text">MAKING ME THIRSTY</div><div id="row4"></div>
<div class="text">BLAH</div><div id="row5"></div>
<div class="text">BLAH</div><div id="row6"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this limited to 1 IE version?

Comment: It certainly happens on IE8 and iirc IE8 with the IE7 rendering engine.

Comment: What happens if you make the wrapper wider ?

Comment: Works for me in IE8 with a doctype.  Seems like an IE7 bug.  You could just put the <div class="text"> inside the <div id="rowX"> but that's just sidestepping the problem...

Answer (score 7):

The floats are being bumped to the next line because of the `width: 270px` on the rows. That happens in IE6/7 because of its [broken float model](http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/floatmodel.html). IE puts the float elements next to the colored row divs instead of overlaying them, but since their combined width is bigger than the width of the wrapper, the colored rows drop down to the next line.

If you really need that maximum width of 270 pixels for those colored bars, you can use `max-width` instead. That doesn't work in IE6, though, so if that's really critical you'll need a work-around for that.

Comment: They shouldn't be though because they are block level elements (ie not inline). Every other browser does it this way.

Comment: Indeed... But IE isn't every other browser. I've clarified my answer a bit.

Answer (score 0):

not sure why your trying to achieve it that way.
but this works.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
div div { height: 1.3em; }
#wrapper { width: 300px; overflow: hidden; }
div.text { float: right; white-space: nowrap; clear: both; background: white; padding-left: 12px; text-align: left; }
#row1, #row2, #row3, #row4, #row5, #row6 { width: 270px; margin-bottom: 4px; }
#row1 { background: red; }
#row2 { background: blue; }
#row3 { background: green; }
#row4 { background: yellow; }
#row5 { background: pink; }
#row6 { background: gray; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("jquery", "1.3.2");
google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
  $(function() {
    $("div.text").animate({ width: "90%" }, 2000);
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="row1"><div class="text">FOO</div></div>
<div id="row2"><div class="text">BAR</div></div>
<div id="row3"><div class="text">THESE PRETZELS ARE</div></div>
<div id="row4"><div class="text">MAKING ME THIRSTY</div></div>
<div id="row5"><div class="text">BLAH</div></div>
<div id="row6"><div class="text">BLAH</div></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```